# Integral involving derivative

Tags: integration

I'm looking at a problem where I want to find the integral of

$\int_{0}^{\alpha} r'(\theta)R(\theta) - r(\theta)R'(\theta) ~d\theta.$

I was thinking that this integrand was almost too perfectly close to a product rule derivative. I continued with a by parts integral letting $u=R(\theta)$ and $dv=r'(\theta)d\theta$ yielding,

$\int_{0}^{\alpha} r'(\theta)R(\theta) d\theta = R(\theta)r(\theta)-\int_{0}^{\alpha}r(\theta)R'(\theta) d\theta.$

Plugging in,

$\int_{0}^{\alpha} r'(\theta)R(\theta) - r(\theta)R'(\theta) ~d\theta=R(\theta)r(\theta)-2\int_{0}^{\alpha}r(\theta)R'(\theta) d\theta.$

With this result, I can envision myself doing by-parts integrals over and over again to no avail unless I knew the parametric form of $r$ and $R$. I tried to do a by parts integral of both pieces, but we just end at the same place. Is there some cute trick to get this to work out?

Comment: What is the relation between $r$ and $R$ ?

Comment: @nicomezi: That would be nice, but the problem is, if $R(\theta)^2=1,$ then differentiating yields $2R(\theta)\,R'\theta)=0,$ forcing $R'(\theta)=0.$ I doubt that's true.

Comment: Ahem, you are right.

Comment: There is no known relationship between R and r, they're simply two arbitrary polar functions.